# How to call an optional function using Selector and NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift-protocols

**Language**: Swift 3

**IDE**: XCode 8.3.2 (8E2002)

I have a protocol with an optional function `foo`

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol {
    @objc optional func foo(_ notification: Notification)
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    func listenToFoo() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.foo(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UltimateNotificationKeyLOL"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

If I extend this code to a **class**, say a `UIViewController`.

```
class CrashingViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.listenToFoo()
    }
}

extension CrashingViewController: SomeProtocol { }
```

Now here comes the problem, since `foo` is an optional function, if any one sends a `Notification` with the key `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UltimateNotificationKeyLOL")` the application will crash because I haven't implemented `foo` yet. So in this case, the above code will cause a crash.

However if I do this

```
class GodzillaViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.listenToFoo()
    }
}

extension GodzillaViewController: SomeProtocol {
    func foo(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("lol")
    }
}
```

No crash is created since `foo(_:)` is not optional anymore.

**Also**: This code isn't possible `#selector(self.foo?(_:))`

**Question**: Is it possible to have a selector call an optional function without crashing the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I where you I would make a full-swift protocol like so:

```
// Protocol declaration
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func foo(_ notification: Notification)
}

// Provide default implementation for optional methods of SomeProtocol
extension SomeProtocol {
    func foo(_ notification: Notification) {}
}

// Extend SomeProtocol with additional methods
extension SomeProtocol {
    func listenToFoo() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UltimateNotificationKeyLOL"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            self.foo(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, doing it like this has multiple benefits:

1. You have a Swift only code (no @objc)
2. By adding a default implementation of `foo`, you made the function optional.
3. Your notification can still call `foo` without crashing as it will go to the default implementation if necessary
4. You can even add some code to the default method if you still want to do something!

**UPDATE**

You can see in the `listenToFoo()` function that I used a different `addObserver` function that uses a closure instead, the reason being that #selector still requires the function to be exposed to @objc and the closure doesn't:

> func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, object obj: Any?, queue: OperationQueue?, using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol

Comment: @Hamish is correct, you can't use NotificationCenter for functions who are not exposed to Obj-C

Comment: @Hamish You are right, I updated the answer to use a different `addObserver` function that doesn't require @objc! Thanks

Comment: @ZonilyJame The `#selector` way of doing it is what requires a method to be exposed to ObjC. There are of course other possibilities like the one I change it to, or if you really want to use selectors for some reason you should look at the Swift variant which works something like this instead `Selector("foo(_:)")`

Comment: Ohhhh, basing from your code I found a solution I wanted to go to. Also I thought the `addObserver(.... block: )` was only supported in iOS 10/9 above, looks like they changed it. But this is also a great implementation which doesn't tell me to make use of @objc